# Clearing terminal causing program to slow down drastically

Tags: python, python-os

I was running a program used to find the number with the longest sequence in the collatz conjecture, and I was trying to implement a progress bar. I successfully did so, in my own weird way, but I noticed that the program was running a lot slower, about 16.5 times slower. This is because of the "system('clear)" command, which I used to make the progress bar. Does anyone know a way to clear the terminal that doesn't slow down the program, or is there no other library and I should just make the progress bar in a different way? Thanks.

```
from os import system


def collatz(N):
   full_sequence = []
   for i in range(2,  N + 1):
       sequence = []
       print(f'{round(((i / N) * 100), 1)}%')
       while i != 1:
           sequence.append(i)
           if i % 2 == 0:
               i = i // 2
           else:
               i = (i * 3) + 1
       sequence.append(1)
       full_sequence.append(sequence)
   return full_sequence


def prob14(list):
   length = []
   for i in range(0, len(list)):
       length.append((len(list[i]),(i + 2)))
   return max(length)


example = collatz(10000)
print(prob14(example))
```

I tried using another library called clear_shell, but it came up as an error in pycharm. I couldn't find any other ways to clear terminal. It does what I was expecting, but it causes the program to run so much slower.

Comment: Where is the call to `system('clear')` in your code?

Comment: Use `tqdm` to make a progress bar.